# Can javascript detect and disable screen-mirroring on browsers in iOS/Android?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, casting, safari, airplay

I have some video content which I cant allow playback on larger screen. So I have disabled airplay (by setting `x-webkit-airplay="deny"` on `<video>` tag), and have disabled chromecast by hiding the icon and preventing casting session establishment. But users can still mirror the whole device screen onto TV at OS level (ios can mirror to AppleTV; Samsung/LG devices can mirror to respective brand TVs by Miracast or WiDi; etc).

Mobile native apps usually have some sort of way to detect mirroring and disallow it by showing some error message. Can Javascript detect the same in browsers?

BTW I found [this](https://www.airbeam.tv/watching-netflix-when-using-screen-mirroring/) which tells me Netflix can detect if content is being mirrored to non-hdcp display in safari browser. Any idea how they do it?

Comment: Hey codneto, just curious if you made any progress with this?

Comment: No. I think its not possible. But one solution is to invest in DRM because iOS doesn't let DRM content mirrored.

Comment: Gotcha. I've pretty much come to the same conclusion. Thanks for the feedback.